# How do I set the app invites email text or at least how do I format it better?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

The app invites email screenshot Google shows on the app invites page https://developers.google.com/app-invites/ looks alright but the ones that I get for my app just have a nasty wall of text above the install button that comes from my app description.

How can I change what it says? or format my app description on the play store so it looks better on that email?  like can I create a paragraph that will be only thing shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is no longer valid as the text can not be passed when creating the invitation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder#setEmailHtmlContent(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Currently email content gets it's description from the play store. The ability to add more customization to the email invitation is a good request and is being considered by the team.

Comment: Is there a way for me to format my play store content so it looks better on the email? like if I use paragraph tags or something?